# Simple if statement not evaluating to true when it should

Tags: c++, debugging, if-statement, visual-studio-2005, logic

```
if ((!m_pMediaPage->PageLayer() || !m_pMediaPage->LoadState()) &&
     !m_pMediaPage->m_bRequestList)
{
    GetListInfo();
    m_pMediaPage->m_bRequestList = TRUE;
}
```

GetListInfo() does not get executed when all values are 0.

PageLayer() and LoadState() return ints and m_bRequestList is an int.

Basically rewritten as this:

```
if ((!0 || !0) && !0)  -or-  if ((1 || 1) && 1)
```

I can only assume that the values being evaluated by the if statement aren't really as seen by the debugger.

I am using visual studio 2005 and put breakpoints on line 1 & 4 to examine the values and see if it executes into the if statement. I am not sure how else to debug this.

Like I said, each of the 3 values are 0 as viewed by the debugger when at breakpoint 1.

Functions in .h:

```
int  PageLayer() {return m_iCurrentLayer;} - protected
BOOL LoadState() {return m_bLoadDone;}     - protected
```

BOOL:

```
typedef int BOOL;
```

Comment: And you stepped thru it with the debugger an confirmed you're getting the return values you expected? You've tried capturing all th evalues up front so you can see them before the if?

Comment: I step through yes and even after repeated continues (F5) it returns back to the same point with the same values and does not go into the if-statement. I have not tried capturing them outside of the if-statement but I don't see why they wouldn't be printed out with the values the debugger claims they have. I will give it a shot though.

Comment: Try stepping into the methods when you are at breakpoint 1 using F10 to verify the return values of the two methods.

Comment: @Enigma The very fact that you can step into `LoadState` proves that things aren't as you say they are. If `PageLayer` was returning zero then your program would not even call `LoadState`. In an expression `A || B` if A is true then B does not get evaluated.

Comment: @john: I should clarify. I am not stepping into the function you mention but just looking at the value that would be returned.

Comment: @Engima, OK thanks for clearing that up, but how complex are the functions? Maybe you're mistaken about what you think they should return. In any case trying to step into them sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @WilliamCustode: I cannot do that per-say as the functions entire contents is just one return of a protected variable. (It's basically an inline)

Comment: Drop the definition of PageLayer and LoadState into multiple lines (put the curly's on their own lines as well as the return) and then you can step into it appropriately. It doesn't matter if it's protected.

Comment: I updated the Q to include the functions. All in all, I might as well just be returning the value itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This conditional statement looks as if it would be executed if all values return from the different functions return zero. If the body of the function isn't executed, I would debug the problem as follows:

1. Log the values of all functions prior to the `if`-statement:

   ```
   std::cout << "page-layer=" << !m_pMediaPage->PageLayer() << ' '
             << "load-state=" << !m_pMediaPage->LoadState() << ' '
             << "request-list=" << !m_pMediaPage->m_bRequestList << '\n';
   ```

   Yes, the debugger should show these values as well but I have great faith in the values being printed to be the values actually evaluated.
2. If that doesn't give the necessary insight into what goes wrong, I would start breaking down the condition into separate parts and verify success at each level, e.g.:

   ```
   if (!m_pMediaPage->PageLAyer()) {
       std::cout << "page-layer is not set\n";\
   }
   if (!m_pMediaPAge->LoadState()) {
       std::cout << "load-state is not set\n";
   ...
   ```
3. If this still doesn't give any insight, I'd start suspecting that the functions return funny values and I would verify that the different results are funny values and I would start looking at the output after preprocesing using the `-E` option.

Comment: I cascaded the if-statements and oddly enough the first one is not even get hit in the debugger. It's as if the breakpoint is not where it is visually from the eyes of the debugger.

Comment: @Enigma: Is it possible that some stale object files are used? Build your project cleanly from scratch! Also, did you see the logged output?

Comment: @Enigma, are you trying to debug a 'release version' of your code? It sounds like you are trying to debug code which has been optimized. That's not usually very helpful because the optimizer has a habit of moving things around so the debugger can't really follow what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged the question as VS2005; do you have all relevant service packs installed to ensure you aren't running into some long-fixed compiler issue?

Secondly, the functions you've listed appear to be very simple setters (you might want to make them const, although that is unrelated to your problem).

You're stepping thru with the debugger, it might therefore be valuable to check your assertion that they are all zero:

```
bool plCond = (m_pMediaPage->PageLayer());
bool lsCond = (m_pMediaPage->LoadState());
bool rlCond = (m_pMediaPage->m_bRequestList);
bool getListInfoCond = ((!cond1 || !cond2) && !cond3);

if (getListInfoCond)
{
    GetListInfo();
    m_pMediaPage->m_bRequestList = TRUE;
}
```

If this fixes the problem, you either have a heisenbug or a stack/memory stomp.

If this doesn't fix the problem, it may home in on the cause.

If this DOES fix the problem, you may want to consult the assembly for the code and see if you have somehow tripped a compiler bug.